# If statement with 3 checkpoints

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have a small if statement which checks if my filenames are correct. At first i only needed 2 names to compare within the if statement.

```
if [ $name == $name3 ]; then
    qsub calculatecorrelation.sh $i $j
fi
```

Now i want to compare 3 names and if all correct continue the script.
My first attempt looks like this but i am not convinced this is the way to do it.

```
if [ $name == $name3 == $name5 ]; then
    qsub calculatecorrelation.sh $i $j $k
fi
```

So how can i check all 3 names to be the same and than continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
if [ $name == $name3 ] && [ $name3 == $name5 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for the logical AND [operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) `&&`:

```
if [ $name == $name3 ] && [ $name3 == $name5 ]; then
```